# Silverlight cross domain calls

Tags: c#, silverlight, html-agility-pack, silverlight-5.0

I am new to Silverlight and especially in URL Access Restrictions in Silverlight 5.
I am trying to use the bellow code to get to any domain, which Apparently I can't due to missing crossdomain.xml and  clientaccesspolicy.xml on those websites.

```
HtmlWeb.LoadAsync("http://www.otherwebsite.com", OnCallback); 

if (htmlDocumentLoadCompleted.Error != null)
{
  var htmlDocument = htmlDocumentLoadCompleted.Document;
  if (htmlDocument !=null)
   {
    MessageBox.Show("Passed!");
   }
}
```

Hence, I have the nasty error :

```
{System.Security.SecurityException ---> System.Security.SecurityException: Security error.
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
```

I've tried several options, in and out browser with and without Elevated Trust. 
So, my question is it possible at all to get it working In or Out the browser?

Answer (score 1):

Service should share cross domain policy. For example [amazon crossdomain](http://www.amazon.com/crossdomain.xml).
This is the only possible way to use the service.

**UPD:**
From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645032):

> Silverlight trusted application is run within an expanded sandbox
>   which allows it to access network and local resources that a normal
>   Silverlight application is explicitly denied the ability to access for
>   security reasons.

So, i think you should give your application [elevated trust](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721083%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) and run it (application) out-of-browser or in-browser (if only under administrator privileges).

Also: [URL Access Restrictions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189008)

Comment: Actually, i was not referring specifically to a service, But, to a plain webpage. It seems that adding a webbrowser control somehow solve this problem, with a overhead of course.

Comment: After your suggestion I tried it again, but without success. I run the application under Elevated trust within the browser and I get the above error. Plus, when I run it out of browser, with elevated trust, I get htmlDocument == null.

Comment: According to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262450/calling-external-websites-from-silverlight?rq=1 It is possible to override the cross domain policy of the server in Silverlight 4 and above. In Silverlight 4 you can with a trusted "out of browser" application.. However the above example still gives me error